# How to test if PyObject has an iterator

Tags: python, c

I am implementing a C function as an extension for Python. Inside `abstract.h`, I found the following:

```
/* ==== Iterators ================================================ */

/* Takes an object and returns an iterator for it.
   This is typically a new iterator but if the argument is an iterator, this
   returns itself. */
PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyObject_GetIter(PyObject *);

/* Returns 1 if the object 'obj' provides iterator protocols, and 0 otherwise.

   This function always succeeds. */
PyAPI_FUNC(int) PyIter_Check(PyObject *);
```

When I try to get iterators using `PyObject_GetIter` on obviously non-iterable objects like a number, I get the error `SystemError: <built-in function xxx> returned a result with an error set`.

```
static PyObject *my_method(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) 
{
    PyObject *obj;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &obj)
    //  printf("\ncheck %d",PyIter_Check(obj)); // always 0
    PyObject *iter = PyObject_GetIter(obj); // throws error
    return PyLong_FromLong(0);
}
```

I would like to handle errors on my own. So I tried to use the `PyIter_Check` to test if the object has an iterator. However, this function returned 0 for all objects I provided, including the iterable ones.

I thought that it might be caused by the `PyAPI_FUNC()` macro but I found it in `pyport.h` and it seems to be only adding `__declspec`.

- Why is the function `PyIter_Check` returning zero for all objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyIter_Check` is for checking whether an object **is** an iterator, not whether it can *provide* one.  There doesn’t appear to be a `PyIterable_Check`.

Moreover, Python pretty much enforces EAFP: since anything could provide an `__iter__` that raises an exception, you have to check for an error from `PyObject_GetIter` anyway, so the only point of the `*_Check` functions is to provide early sanity checks (sometimes with better error messages).

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful. I'm going to study the [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html):)

Comment: @thehorseisbrown: Aside from appropriate `Py_DECREF`s for extant owned references, you can usually just say `PyObject *const x=Py_Foo(…); if(!x) return 0;`.